# RSelenium not connecting and chrome drivers do not update

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am working with a MAC M2 cip. I am trying to do a very simple download of all the PDF from a website page ( https://digitalcollections.archives.nysed.gov/index.php/Detail/collections/7782 ) but I am having problems with the RSelenium package for scraping for R.

This is the code I am trying to use.

###################################################

```
# Start Selenium server
selServ <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 6745L)

# Start Chrome browser
 remDr <- selServ[["client"]]

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
remDr$navigate("https://digitalcollections.archives.nysed.gov/index.php/Detail/collections/7782")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

###
binman::list_versions("chromedriver")

# Navigate to webpage
remDr$navigate("https://digitalcollections.archives.nysed.gov/index.php/Detail/collections/7782")

# Find links to PDF files
 pdf_links <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", value = "a[href$='.pdf']")

# Download PDF files
 for (i in 1:length(pdf_links)) {
  # Get link for PDF file
  pdf_link <- pdf_links[[i]]$getElementAttribute("href")[[1]]
  # Download file
  remDr$navigate(pdf_link)
  Sys.sleep(2)
  # Rename file with the last part of the URL
  file_name <- sub('.*/', '', pdf_link)
  # Save file to download directory
  remDr$saveScreenshot(file.path(download.dir, file_name))
}
```

## Quit browser and server

```
remDr$close()
selServ$stop()
```

#######################################

And these are the errors I get

#######################################

## Start Selenium server

```
 selServ <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 6745L)
```

checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 6745 after 0 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 6745L) :
Could not determine server status.

> ## Start Chrome browser

```
remDr <- selServ[["client"]]
remDr$open()
```

[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) :
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 6745 after 0 ms: Connection refused

#######################################

The problem might be with the chrome drivers. My chrome version is 113.0.5672.92 but on Rstudio there are these chrome drive versions only:

`binman::list_versions("chromedriver")`
$mac64_m1
[1] "105.0.5195.19" "105.0.5195.52" "106.0.5249.21"

And I tried to update the chrome drivers using this website https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and positioning the dowloaded file in usr\lib\bin but I still get only the old chromedriver on Rstudio.

Thank you.